# Reading value from dynamically created button in Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a virtual keyboard and am trying to fill an input box with the letters that appear on the button. I have the following functions:

This function takes a character and makes a button with the char as its value:

```
function keyButton(char) {
  var btn = document.createElement("button"); //create button
  btn.innerText = char; //fill it with char
  btn.id = "btn";
  keyStroke()
  return btn;
}
```

This function creates a button for all letters:

```
var keyList = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
for (i in keyList)
{
  var button = keyButton(keyList[i]);
  document.body.appendChild(button)
}
```

This function is the problem, it should read the value from the button and append it to the input box:

```
function keyStroke() {
  document.getElementById("searchBar").value += document.getElementById("btn").innerText;
}
```

The HTML for the input box is like so:

```
<input id="searchBar" class="inputBar" placeholder="Enter something" />
```

Comment: 1. every single one of your buttons has the exact same (supposedly unique) id: `btn` 2. keyStroke() is called when you define a button, not when you click it

Comment: You need to create a click event handler, and probably read the value from the button's `value` property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var keyList = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";

for (var i in keyList) {    //loop through letters in keyList
  var button = keyButton(keyList[i]);
  document.body.appendChild(button);
}

function keyButton(char) {
  var btn = document.createElement("button"); //create button
  btn.innerHTML = char; //fill it with char
  btn.onclick = function () { keyStroke(this); };
  return btn;
}

function keyStroke(b) {
  document.getElementById("searchBar").value += b.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<input id="searchBar" class="inputBar" placeholder="Enter something" />
```

Comment: innerText is [non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText), it would be better to use a property like `value`

Comment: @aross Thanks, changed to `.innerHTML`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works just fine. A question though: What is `function () { keyStroke(this); };` I've never seen a function being called that way.

Comment: That's the point; I'm not actually calling anything in that line. I'm setting an anonymous function as the button's `onclick`. When the button is clicked, the anonymous function is called, and only then is the command inside actually executed. Otherwise, like I said, `keyStroke(this)` would be executed right away, as opposed to whenever the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

if you create an event handler for the buttons click event where you created it you can get the data of the button when the button is clicked

```
function keyButton(char) {
  var btn = document.createElement("button"); //create button
  btn.innerText = char; //fill it with char
  btn.id = "btn";
  btn.onclick = function() {//yourcodehere}
  keyStroke()
  return btn;
}
```

or you still can use the function you have created

```
function keyButton(char) {
  var btn = document.createElement("button"); //create button
  btn.innerText = char; //fill it with char
  btn.id = "btn";
  btn.onclick = keyStroke;
  keyStroke()
  return btn;
}
```

but this way you need to change the `keyStroke` function a little bit, to get the event's source.

```
function keyStroke(evt) {
  document.getElementById("searchBar").value += evt.target.innerText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

find working solution below:

adding button with label

```
function keyButton(chara) {
var btn = document.createElement("button"); //create button
btn.innerText = chara; //fill it with char
btn.id = "btn";
btn.onclick=onclickFunction;
return btn;
}
```

onclick of button function:

```
function onclickFunction(ev){
var searchBar=document.getElementById('searchBar');
searchBar.value=searchBar.value + ev.srcElement.innerText;
}
```